# Send a parameter in main and use it in widget's build (Flutter dart)

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile

I have a main.dart file. I want to create button section wigdet with Tapboxes. But every Tapbox have to have own value in it.

```
Widget buttonSection = Container(
  child: Row(
   // mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
    children: [
      Column(
        children: [ 
          Tapbox(5),
          Tapbox(4),
        ],
      ),
     Column(
        children: [ 
          Tapbox(12),
          Tapbox(8),
        ],
      ),
  ),
);
```

This is my all tapbox wigdet file:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
 class TapboxA extends StatefulWidget {
  TapboxA({
   Key key, 
    this.number1,
     }) : super(key: key);
  final number1;
 @override
 _TapboxAState createState() => _TapboxAState();
 }
 class _TapboxAState extends State<TapboxA> {
 bool _active = false;

 void _handleTap() {
   setState(() {
   _active = !_active;
  });
}
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return GestureDetector(
  onTap: _handleTap,
  child: Container(
    child: Center(
      child: Text(
        _active ? "Tapbox parameter value" : "Tapbox parameter value",
        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12.0, color: Colors.white),
      ),
    ),
    width: 60.0,
    height: 60.0,
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      color: _active ? Colors.lightGreen[700] : Colors.grey[600],
    ),
  ),
 );
}
}
```

But when I get parameter in Tapbox, I can not access in state part. How can I fix this code.

Comment: I am gonna give all paramaters in main because they will come with an random array.

Comment: use widget.number1 you can access in state part of tapbox.

Comment: @MayurChaudhary thanks for the answer. But now vscode asking me getter for widget use. How can I add getter?

Comment: it's widget not Widget. you should keep "w" lowercase.

Answer (score 0):

use here model is list passing to next widget

```
                           Navigator.push(
                                  context,
                                  MaterialPageRoute(
                                    builder: (context) => TaskDetailsPage(
                                      detail: model,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                );
```

to next page or widget
here asset is list you can write String getData;

```
class TaskDetailsPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final Asset detail;

  TaskDetailsPage({
    Key key,
    @required this.detail,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _TaskDetailsPageState createState() => _TaskDetailsPageState();
}
```

and access is

```
                   Text(
                      widget.detail.title,
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24),
                    ),
```